# Storing images as a blob in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

So I have searched high and low for a relevant answer, and I have yet to find one, so I'm just going to ask the question myself. In my MySQL tables I have 5 columns of `id, customer__id, file_data, file_name, mime_type`the relevant one here is `file_data` which is a type of `LONGBLOB`. Now from what I understand the size of files that a `LONGBLOB` can handle is pretty substantial but when I try to upload a file that is around 978 KB it fails, could it be that the dimensions of the image are too large `(2048 x 1536)`?

Here is the code for my uploader. It works very elegantly for things like excel sheets, pdf, word documents, and other stuff, but when it comes to images it fails:

```
<?php 
    require_once '../../inc/config.php';
    $response = array();
    $response['errors'] = false;
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    if(!empty($_FILES)){
        //set default data arrays
        $names = array(); //stores file names
        $files = array(); //stores the file data
        $mime_types = array(); //store the file type as a mime type

        //force each file name to the names array
        foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $name){
            array_push($names, $name);
        }
        //force the file data into its own array spot in the files array
        foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $temp){
            array_push($files, prepareImageDBString($temp));
        }
        //force the mimetypes into the mime_types array
        foreach($_FILES['file']['type'] as $type){
            array_push($mime_types, $type);
        }

        //process all three of the file arrays simultaneously so that no data is left out
        for($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++){
            $file_name = $names[$i];
            $file_data = $files[$i];
            $mime_type = $mime_types[$i];

            //set the query for the data to go into the note_file table in the database 
            $q = "INSERT INTO brb.files (customer__id, file_name, file_data, mime_type)
            VALUES('$id', '$file_name', '$file_data', '$mime_type')";
            //run the query
            if($stmt = $CONN->prepare($q)){
            //process any errors that may occur

                if(!$stmt->execute()){
                    printf("Error Message: %s\n", $CONN->error);
                }
            }
        }

    }


    echo json_encode($response);

    function prepareImageDBString($filepath){
        $out = 'null';
        $handle = fopen($filepath, 'r');
        if($handle){
            $content = fread($handle, filesize($filepath));
            $content = bin2hex($content);
            fclose($handle);
            $out = $content;
        }

        return $out;
    }
?>
```

If someone could point me in the direction that would be fantastic. Please do not provide be an answer on why the practice is bad, I'm aware it's bad practice and know what proper practice is, this is a learning tool for myself and nothing more, just bear with me on it for a minute.

Thank you to everyone who provides help!

Comment: MySQL definitely doesn't care about the dimensions of the file. The filesize perhaps.

Comment: the file size is of type `.jpg` and the size is `874KB` so I don't see how this is failing

Comment: have you tried substantially small files?

Comment: yes the one I tested to start was  `32 Kb`

Comment: _"it fails"_ is pretty vague.  What is the error displayed?

Comment: it's not tossing back an error message at all

Comment: OK, then how does it fail?

Comment: Also, for images you probably want `rb` in the `fopen()` call.

Comment: it just doesn't perform the insert. Which is weird because if it isn't inserting then shouldn't it toss back there error

Comment: Did you try serialize() before insertion and unserialize() upon retrieval ? base64_encode() and base64_decode() may also help.

Comment: so is the problem possibly in my `prepareImageDBString` function?